# How to use Actors/Groups with ShapeRenderer instead of Batch?

Tags: libgdx

I am intersted in using Actors and Groups on a Stage so that I can make components and subcomponents which draw relative to their parents, but I intend to do my drawing with a ShapeRenderer instead of a Batch.  From what I understand of an Actor, the batch which is passed in to the draw() method has all of its matrices set up properly so that I can just use a coordinate system WITHIN THE PARENT to lay out the subcomponents.  But it seems that this coordinate system is focused on Batches, and I want to draw using a ShapeRenderer.

What do I have to do to get the child Actors to draw themselves RELATIVE TO THEIR PARENT (rather than in global coordinates) when drawing them with ShapeRenderers?

Also, one other question:  How should I be managing begining/ending the ShapeRenderer?  I am currently passing in a reference to a global ShapeRenderer when I construct my parent object, and this parent object passes in references to each of its children.  Should I be calling begin() end() separately in the draw method of each parent/child actor?  Or should I call it in my main app's draw() method, so I'm only calling it once each frame?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my `HorizontalLine` class. If you create one, set it's width and weight (height) and you can add it to a container like `Table` or so. It will use it's `getX()` and `getY()` methods to draw itself on coordinates relative to it's parent.

This answer will also help you to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075414/getting-stage-coordinates-of-actor-in-table-in-libgdx

```
public class HorizontalLine extends Actor {

    private ShapeRenderer sr;


    public HorizontalLine(float width, float weight, Color color){
        setSize(width,weight);
        setColor(color);

        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
        sr.setAutoShapeType(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        batch.end();

        Vector2 coords = new Vector2(getX(),getY());

        Color color = new Color(getColor());
        sr.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
        sr.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);



        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);


        sr.rectLine(coords.x,coords.y,coords.x + getWidth(), coords.y, getHeight());
        sr.end();
        Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(1f);
        sr.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        batch.begin();
    }
}
```

Also, you should end the batch, begin the renderer, end it, and begin the batch again in each actor cause otherwise it will mess up in future. Remember that `ShapeRenderer` calls are expensive. Remember to set `SR` and `Batch's` color back to white when you finish.

Comment: very helpful, should be part of the docu

Comment: The answer is indeed very helpful. thanks. but remember that a shaperenderer is disposable, so it must be disposed. Just in case someone copies this example and decides to use it to draw hundreds of lines.